# Calculate the angle of a vector in compass (360) direction

Tags: trigonometry

Given a vector described by X and Y components

$x=4$

$ y=-2$

I get the direction of the vector by using $\arctan{-\frac 24}$.

$\theta= -0.4636 \text{ rad}$

$\theta=  -26.565^{\circ}$

My initial confusion was that I assumed the degrees in theta referred to a compass direction as would be measured with a protractor. But a vector of 4,-2 ends up in the 2nd quadrant somewhere between 90 and 180, so I know -26 is not my true compass direction of the vector.

So my question is, how do you convert the theta direction of a vector to a compass bearing (0-360 degrees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0^\circ$ for $\arctan$ is to the right, along the $+x$ axis increasing counterclockwise. $(4,-2)$ is in the $4$th quadrant, at $-26$ degrees.  On a compass $0^\circ$ is North, straight up increasing clockwise. Compass $=90^\circ-\arctan(+180^\circ)$, but you need to account for a sign ambiguity, which is expressed by the $(+180)$.  To avoid that problem, you can use $atan2(x,y)$, which returns the mathematical angle and keeps track of the quadrant for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I'm thinking that 0 degrees is my North, and I have to deal with the potential for my vectors to fall in any quadrant- would it be safe to use the following rules to determine compass direction: if(x > 0 & y < 0) -> 90-theta, if(x < 0 & y < 0) -> 270-theta, if(x > 0 & y > 0) -> 90-theta, if(x < 0 & y > 0) -> 270-theta

Comment: Looks good to me, more trouble than atan2, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working solely in degrees, the following equation will transform your angle from polar coordinates (0 at x, 0 going CCW) to compass angle (0 at 0, y going CW)

(450 - θ) % 360

where % is the modulus function

Answer (score 1):

The tangent function has period $180^\circ.$ Hence, for any integer $n$, we have $\tan(\arctan(x)+180n^\circ)=x$. The arctangent function gives values in the degree interval $(-90,90)$. In particular, then, if $\arctan(x)<0^\circ,$ and you want a positive angle whose tangent is $x,$ then you need only look at $\arctan(x)+180^\circ$ and $\arctan(x)+360^\circ,$ choosing the one that puts you in the correct quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

A formula that give the compass direction .

Start 0 degrees from the north and increasing clockwise from 0 to 360 degrees.

f(x,y)=180/pi()* (pi()-pi()/2*(1+sign(y))* (1-sign(x^2))-pi()/4*(2+sign(y))*sign(x)

```
   -sign(x*y)*atan((abs(y)-abs(x))/(abs(y)+abs(x))))
```

The formula is working for any value of x and y.

For x=y=o the result is undefined.